# Project doesn`t have access to referenced project in the c# solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I'm trying to access a method from a class which is in another project but in the same solution. The problem i face is that it keeps saying that i'm missing a reference even when i'm using the using namespace of the project.

This code is in project 2 and it is a controller. which is referenced to project 1

```
        namespace WebSvc1.Controllers
     {
public class RemunerationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void BonusRecipient(BonusRecipients bonusRecipients)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BonusRecipients));

        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +
            "//BonusReipients.xml";

        FileStream file = File.Create(path);

        writer.Serialize(file, bonusRecipients);
        file.Dispose();
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

}

And this code is in project 1 which should call the method from the controller in project 2

```
     using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Net.Http;
     using System.Net.Http.Headers;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Web.Mvc;
     using Newtonsoft.Json;
      using WebApp1.DataContracts;
    using WebApp1.Models;

   namespace WebApp1.Controllers
     {
       public class BonusController : Controller
         {
           // GET: Bonus
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
             return View("View");
             }

    // POST: Bonus/Allocate
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Allocate(BonusViewModel bonusAllocation)
    {

        try
        {
            var employees = await GetEmployees();
            List<Employee> recipients = new List<Employee>();

            for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % bonusAllocation.OneInXEmployees == 0)
                {
                    var recipient = employees[i];
                    recipients.Add(recipient);
                    employees.Remove(recipient);
                }
            }

            //BonusRecipient(recipients);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("View");
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57652/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
       MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await 
      client.GetAsync($"api/employee");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string employeeData = await 
      response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<Employee> employees = 
         JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(employeeData);

            return employees;
        }

        return new List<Employee>();
    }
  }
   }
```

Comment: You need to add the one project as a reference to the other project.  How exactly you do that depends on your framework target (.NET Framework, or .NET Core), and your IDE.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019

Comment: @SamAxe I already added a reference from my main project to my second one. They are both MVC applications and they both need to run.

Comment: Well, since you haven't shown us the relevant parts of the project, I'm not sure I can help you much more.  Update your question with the bits of your project that have an impact on your question.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but you appear to be attempting to call `BonusRecipient` method directly, as if it were a member of the class that contains `Allocate`. Is that correct? Because that'll never work. You need to create an instance and call the method on that instance.

Comment: @SamAxe Done - Hopefully now it makes sense. basically i have 2 controllers as you can see. And the WebSvc1 i referenced it into WebApp1. So i`m trying to access via using WebSvc1; and then use whatever method is inside the controller. Hopefully is the right thing to do

Comment: @JohnWu Correct, even if i`m trying to use the namespace of WebSvc1 it complains, without the namespace i cannot create the instance of that controller which has the method in it.

Comment: A namespace along is not enough, your project has to reference the project that contains the types you're trying to use.

Comment: Please post the actual, complete error message (copy and paste is best) and indicate the line on which it occurs in your code example.

Comment: It occurs to me, OP, that what you are trying to do is remarkably odd. Normally, if two web projects need to talk to each other, it would be via a web service call, e.g. using `HttpClient` and REST. Or if a local call is needed, you'd extract the logic to a library and set a reference from both MVC projects. What is going on here, exactly? Perhaps there is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in this question.

Comment: The last comment from @JohnWu is spot-on... "_extract the logic to a library and reference/call that library from both MVC projects_"  You can probably figure out how to make it work by continuing in the direction you are currently headed but it will forever be a pain point.

Comment: While a shared class or library will improve this example, it will encounter the same problem in the title if the OP can't solve that.

Comment: Noted! Thanks guys